# Formatting issue in IPython/pandas

Tags: pandas, string-formatting, jupyter-notebook

hopefully I'm looking to use pandas and IPython to return some HTML embed codes that I'd like to copy and paste.

The problem is that the output is cropped. How do I change the settings so I can see the full result?

Here's an example:

```
<h2>Evil Trent</h2><iframe width="560" height=...
```

If I select individual elements using the df.ix[0] you can see the full result.

```
<h2>Evil Trent</h2><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/qvX8cfMUPqg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><p>Published by Evan Leonard on Monday August 05.</p>
```

What I'd like is to see the the rest of the output. Is it a simple setting issue in IPython on Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `option.display.max_colwidth` to something larger:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                                                   0
0  <h2>Evil Trent</h2><iframe width="560" height=...

In [12]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth
Out[12]: 50
```

Increasing to 200 seems to do it:

```
In [13]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 200

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
                                                                                                                                                                                              0
0  <h2>Evil Trent</h2><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/qvX8cfMUPqg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><p>Published by Evan Leonard on Monday August 05.</p>
```

*See ["working with package options" section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#working-with-package-options).*

Comment: Brilliant. I owe you again.